# Magneto 2.3 - How to redirect when customer click add to cart button with out logged in

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, cart

I want to redirect the customer when they click Add to Cart without logged in. I had done some action or event with this below code but it is not working.I had tried it is showing oly the error message is there any suggestion to get solution for this.

**app\code\Vendor\AddtoCartRedirction\etc\frontend\event.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation='urn:magento:framework/Event/etc/events.xsd'>
        <event name="controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add">
            <observer name="restrict_cart_add_before" instance="Vendor\AddtoCartRedirction\Observer\ForceCustomerLoginObserver" />
        </event>
</config>
```

**app/code/Vendor/AddtoCartRedirction/Observer**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\AddtoCartRedirction\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class ForceCustomerLoginObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $responseFactory;

    private $scopeConfig;

    private $customerSession;

    private $context;

    private $contextHttp;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $contextHttp,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Url $customerUrl,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory $responseFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url
    ) {
        $this->scopeConfig     = $scopeConfig;
        $this->context         = $context;
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->contextHttp     = $contextHttp;
        $this->messageManager = $context->getMessageManager();
        $this->responseFactory = $responseFactory;        
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $isLoggedIn = $this->contextHttp->getValue(\Magento\Customer\Model\Context::CONTEXT_AUTH);

        if (!$isLoggedIn) {
                $this->messageManager->addError(__('Please Login to add the product in to cart'));
                //set false if you not want to add product to cart
                $observer->getRequest()->setParam('product', false);
                return $this;
         }

    }
}
```

The code shows the Error message after the page loads, but i want to show when clicking the add to cart button.

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using this observer instead

```
   namespace Vendor\AddtoCartRedirction\Observer;

    class ForceCustomerLoginObserver implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
    {

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        # check if user is logged in
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
        if(!$customerSession->isLoggedIn())
        {
            $request = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http');
            //get instance for URL interface
            /** @var \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlInterface */
            $urlInterface = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\UrlInterface');
            // URL to redirect to
            $url = $urlInterface->getUrl('customer/account/login');
            if(strpos($request->getPathInfo(), '/customer/account/') !== 0)
            {
                # redirect to /customer/account/login
                $observer->getControllerAction()
                    ->getResponse()
                    ->setRedirect($url);
            }
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: First i thank for responding, In this i can't go to any other page it is redirecting. In my case i want to redirect when add to cart button is clicked want show the message and redirect or only showing the message.

Comment: Please give any alternate solution @Mr Zid

Answer (score 0):

Keep the backend validation code. We should implement some logic on Frontend.

Mixins `catalog-add-to-cart.js`

*app/code/Vendor/Catalog/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js*

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Catalog/js/catalog-add-to-cart': {
                'Vendor_Catalog/js/catalog-add-to-cart-mixins': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

*app/code/Vendor/Catalog/view/frontend/web/js/catalog-add-to-cart-mixins.js*

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/confirm',
    'mage/url',
], function ($, customerData, confirmation, url) {
    'use strict';

    return function (widget) {

        $.widget('mage.catalogAddToCart', widget, {
            /**
             * Init
             */
            initialize: function () {
                this._super();
                url.setBaseUrl(window.authenticationPopup.baseUrl);
            },

            /**
             * Handler for the form 'submit' event
             *
             * @param {jQuery} form
             */
            submitForm: function (form) {
                var self = this;
                var customer = customerData.get('customer');
                if (!customer().firstname) {
                    confirmation({
                        title: $.mage.__('Login'),
                        content: $.mage.__('Please Login to add the product in to cart'),
                        actions: {
                            confirm: function(){
                                $.mage.redirect(url.build('customer/account/login'));
                            },
                            cancel: function(){},
                            always: function(){}
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    this.ajaxSubmit(form);
                }
            },
        });

        return $.mage.catalogAddToCart;
    }
});
```

[image]